# axios interceptor navigate (use history) with react-router-dom v6.3.0 and unstable_HistoryRouter

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I have interceptor which basically if error doing post request for new access and refresh token, but if new refresh token is no longer valid i need to redirect automatically to ("/"). Prefer to use `useNavigate`

But `useNavigate` could be used only inside react component.

I start googled and found that in react-router-dom from 6 version maintain global history and it has access anywhere.

I tried  to `history push("/")` but it has no affect and i have no idea why it doesn't work. What i'm missing?

App.tsx

```
export let history = createBrowserHistory();


const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function App() {
  return (

      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <HistoryRouter history={history}>
             <Views />
        </HistoryRouter>
      </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

interceptors(axios_instance.js):

```
import history from './App'

const refreshAccessToken = async (navigate) => {
    try{
        const res = await axiosInstanceRefresh.post(
            `${baseUrl}auth/refresh`,
            null,
            {headers: {'Authorization':`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')}`}}
        )
    }catch{
        console.log('NEED TO USE RELOGIN') // works
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken') // works
        localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken') // works
        history.push('/'); // Doesn't work
    }
    return await res.json()
}



axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async request => {
    request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`;
    return request;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});


axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
}, async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        const access_token = await refreshAccessToken();
        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)

});

export default axiosInstance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import history from './App'` is the `App` component, not the `history` object. I think you meant to import the named `history` export from `./App`.

Example:

```
import { history } from './App';
```